# Estimate amount of emails handled by Exim

Tags: email-server, exim

I have two mail servers that use Exim, one is dedicated to receiving mail and the other is dedicated to sending mail.

How can I count how many emails a server sent in a month and how many emails were received in the month by Exim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`eximstats`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/eximstats) command. It parses exim's log files, printing all sort of statistics. The output begins with a summary with the numbers you need, like this:

```
Exim statistics from 2023-01-12 12:40:01 to 2023-02-10 15:02:35

Grand total summary
-------------------
                                                                  At least one address
  TOTAL               Volume   Messages Addresses     Hosts      Delayed       Failed
  Received             775MB       7254                1279      14  0.2%    404  5.6%
  Delivered            829MB       8249      9425       103
  Rejects                          4279                 752
  Temp Rejects                      541                  52
```